# Unable to trigger an update with Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am new to redux and I am trying to build a simple Hello World to try out this library. However, I am having trouble with getting the value in the Home component. The two buttons should trigger two different changes. I think the errors must have something to do with the connect method. After hours of research, I still cannot figure out why it does not work. Thank you in advance.

Below is my code:

Home.js -> component

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import * as actionCreators from "../actions/display.js";
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";

const Home = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      Message:
      <h1>{props.message}</h1>
      <button onClick={props.sayHi}>SayHI</button>
      <button onClick={props.sayHello}>Say Hello</button>
    </div>
  );
};
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { ...state };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators(
    {
      ...actionCreators
    },
    dispatch
  );
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Home);
```

App.js

```
import React from "react";

import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";

import createHistory from "history/createBrowserHistory";
import { Route } from "react-router";

import {
  ConnectedRouter,
  routerReducer,
  routerMiddleware
} from "react-router-redux";
import Home from "./components/Home";
import reducers from "./reducers/reducer"; // Or wherever you keep your reducers

// Create a history of your choosing (we're using a browser history in this case)
const history = createHistory();

// Build the middleware for intercepting and dispatching navigation actions
const middleware = routerMiddleware(history);

// Add the reducer to your store on the `router` key
// Also apply our middleware for navigating
const store = createStore(
  combineReducers({
    ...reducers,
    router: routerReducer
  }),
  applyMiddleware(middleware)
);

const App = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    {/* ConnectedRouter will use the store from Provider automatically */}
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <Route path="/" component={Home} />
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>
);

export default App;
```

reducer.js

```
import { SAY_HELLO, SAY_HI } from "../constants";

const initialState = {
  message: "Mark"
};
const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SAY_HELLO:
      return { ...state, message: "Hello Mark" };
    case SAY_HI:
      return { ...state, message: "Hi Mark" };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default reducer;
```

actions/display.js

```
import { SAY_HELLO, SAY_HI } from "../constants";

export const sayHello = () => ({
  type: SAY_HELLO
});
export const sayHi = () => ({
  type: SAY_HI
});
```

constants.js

```
export const SAY_HELLO = "SAY_HELLO";
export const SAY_HI = "SAY_HI";
```

**Update:**

I figured a working solution for my code but not an ideal one. I change state=>({message:state.message}) to state=>state which means now my component subscrubes to the global state. I also change{props.message} to {props.defaultmessage} in the hi tag on Home.js. Below is the updated code.

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { sayHello, sayHi } from "../actions/display.js";

const Home = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      Message:
      {console.log(props.default.message)}
      <h1>{props.default.message}</h1>
      <button onClick={props.sayHi}>SayHI</button>
      <button onClick={props.sayHello}>Say Hello</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default connect(state => state, {
  sayHello,
  sayHi
})(Home);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in that part of your code:

```js
const store = createStore(
  combineReducers({
    ...reducers,
    router: routerReducer
  }),
  applyMiddleware(middleware)
);
```

`reducers` variable contains reducer function, but you are using it as object here.
You should assign your reducer with a specific key in the state, for example `data`:

```js
const store = createStore(
  combineReducers({
    data: reducers,
    router: routerReducer
  }),
  applyMiddleware(middleware)
);
```

Next, message value will be available at `state.data` path:

```js
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { message: state.data.message };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hoop it work!

```js
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { sayHi, sayHello } from "../actions/display.js";

const Home = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      Message:
      <h1>{props.message}</h1>
      <button onClick={props.sayHi}>SayHI</button>
      <button onClick={props.sayHello}>Say Hello</button>
    </div>
  );
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { message: state.message };
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { sayHi, sayHello })(Home);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing shows up with this change in the <h1> tag.